# Execute callbacks on Annotated fields and methods in Java

Tags: java, annotations, java-annotations

In Java, I'd like to monitor state of annotated fields and method's return values. 
How do I execute a callback on an annotated field value / method return values.

What I'm trying to do : Creating a custom debugger of a sort which would execute some validations on runtime.

Ex:

```
@ObservableMethod
CashFlowSet getCashFlows() {
      @ObservableField
      CashFlowSet set = generateFlows();
}
```

During runtime, I'd like to have a callback on every time the value of set changes and every time getCashFlows() exit the call stack.

Comment: You can use interceptors or other forms of AOP... But inspecting local variables seems like a long shot...

Comment: Could you elaborate on interceptors / AOP frameworks. Are there any which I can use to annotate my code and request callback?